# Difficulty in specifying mesh refinement

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I am trying to give a region within a 3D volume a finer mesh than the rest of the volume. My problem is more complicated but here is a minimum working example.

I define a 3D cuboid and try and have a fine mesh in a region between an inner and outer hemisphere.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Len = 150/1000;  (*length of plate  *)
ht = 15/1000; (* height *)
wd = 80/1000; (* width *)
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  Cuboid[{-Len/2, -wd/2, 0}, {Len/2, wd/2, ht}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
   rcp = 0.02;
mrf = Compile[{{c, _Real, 2}, {a, _Real, 0}},
   Block[{d, com},
    com = Total[c]/3;
    d = Norm[com];
    If[0.8 rcp < d < 1.2 rcp && a > 10^-10, True, False]
    ]
   ];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MeshRefinementFunction -> mrf];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], 
 PlotRange -> {{-Len/2, Len/2}, {-wd/2, wd/2}, {0, ht/4}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This clearly shows an annulus on the boundary but it is not the correct size. If I extract the boundary points and plot them together with the circles defining the region of refinement we see that the annulus is too small.

```
cc = mesh["Coordinates"];
c1 = Select[cc, #[[3]] == 0 &];
ListPlot[c1[[All, {1, 2}]], 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.03, 0.03}, {-0.03, 0.03}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {Circle[{0, 0}, 0.8 rcp], Circle[{0, 0}, 1.2 rcp],
   Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, 0}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Have I done something silly? What is wrong? I know I am taking my reference from the centroid of each element and this will make a slight difference but if I increase the `"MaxCellMeasure"` it does not change the position.

**Edit**

Due to Henrik Schumacher and user21, who have very sharp eyes, they show an elementary mistake. I averaged the 4 points defining the element by dividing by 3. I probably picked this up by copying the `MeshRefinementFunction` from a 2D problem. Here is the corrected version. I use `Mean` as a variant on the two other methods given in their answer.

```
rcp = 0.02;
mrf = Compile[{{c, _Real, 2}, {a, _Real, 0}},
   Block[{d, com},
    com = Mean[c];
    d = Norm[com];
    If[0.8 rcp < d < 1.2 rcp && a > 10^-10, True, False]
    ]
   ];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MeshRefinementFunction -> mrf];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], 
 PlotRange -> {{-Len/2, Len/2}, {-wd/2, wd/2}, {0, ht/4}}]

cc = mesh["Coordinates"];
c1 = Select[cc, #[[3]] == 0 &];
ListPlot[c1[[All, {1, 2}]], 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.03, 0.03}, {-0.03, 0.03}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {Circle[{0, 0}, 0.8 rcp], Circle[{0, 0}, 1.2 rcp],
   Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, 0}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All working properly now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to generate a tet mesh, so

```
com = Total[c]/4;
```

or better

```
com = Total[c]/Length[c];
```

would be more appropriate.

Comment: We are dealing with tets here. It's a coincidence that a 2D quad has 4 vertices and a 3D tet has 4 too.

Comment: But it's a good idea to use `Length[c]` in stead of a fixed number and I updated the ToElementMesh documentation to use that.

Comment: @user21 Aaah, that makes sense.

Comment: I made an edit. I hope that if fine? `reg` is not relevant here. It's only the boundary that is given to TetGen and then, during the mesh generation of the tets the relevant tets are refined.

Comment: @user21 It's all fine. Thank you! My quick fix was a bit too quick... =)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You have sharp eyes to see my mistake. Thank you. I have edited the problem and used `Mean` which is a further variant for the code.  Why does one stare at code for so long and not spot elementary mistakes?